# mongo aggregate query to find records having given time difference between consecutive records of each type

Tags: mongodb, time, aggregate, difference, group

I have mongo collection with data records coming from gps device in every 2-3 second, data sample is as shown here

```
1. {imei:123456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp} 
2. {imei:223456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp} 
3. {imei:123456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp} 
4. {imei:323456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp}
5. {imei:223456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp} 
6. {imei:223456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp} 
7. {imei:323456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp}
```

... around 2 billion records

my requirement is to create aggregate query to find all `imei`s for which time difference between 2 consecutive records is >= given time in minutes for a particular date time.

like for `imei:223456..` above records will be as below:

```
- a. {imei:223456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp} 
- b. {imei:223456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp}
- c. {imei:223456.., port:8000,createdon:timestamp, updatedon : timestamp}
```

if for a given date time these records are considered then
time diff  `b.createdon - a.createdon` => let say 2 min similarly `c.createdon - b.createdon` = 3 min

if given time is 3 minutes then `imei:223456..` is considered as there is a matching time difference record, otherwise it is dropped from the output.

I have tried query as following but its not giving the correct result

```js
collection
  .aggregate([{
      $match: {
        "createdon": // filter out all items that are inside a range 
        {
          $gte: start_dt,
          $lte: end_dt
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$imei",
        max_time: {$max: "$createdon"},
        min_time: {$min: "$createdon"}
      }
    },
    {
      $set: {
        difference: {
          $divide: [{$subtract: ["$max_time", "$min_time"]}, 60 * 1000]
        } // get difference in minutes
      }
    },
    {
      $match: { // filter out all items that are having difference >= 3 min or any given time
        difference: {$gte: minutes}
      }
    }
  ]);
```

request params `start_dt= new Date('02-24-2023').getTime()`, `end_dt= new Date('02-25-2023').getTime()`, and time diff `minutes = 3`, as a result I should get all IMEIs for those any 2 consecutive records difference is exceeding given time 3 min

Comment: What is the [BSON type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/) of `timestamp`?  For example, is it a 32/64-bit integer (milliseconds since some epoch?), double (milliseconds ...), date, timestamp, etc.?

Comment: Please provide the sample data and your examples including the `createdon` values

Comment: It is not clear what is the expected output in a case of a gap. For example, for allowed 3 minutes gap, what if we have: `1, 2, 3, 4, 18, 19, 20`? Should we keep only `18, 19, 20`?

Comment: Sample json is {
  "imei": 1234567890123456,
  "avldt": 1681839734000, 
  "createdon": 1682499349758, its time in millisecond
  "updatedon": 1682499564900
}

Comment: in case of 1, 2, 3, 4, 18, 19, 20 we need to have all values >=3 means , 3, 4, 18 ,19 ,20 etc, out put should have list of records of this type {imei:123....., max_time: source, min_time :timestamp, timediff:} max_time and min_time = createdon timestamp of records whose time difference we have taken in this case , 3, 4, 18 etc.

Comment: I don't mean that the difference is `1, 2, 3, 4, 18, 19, 20`, I mean in case that this is the minutes value of the `createdon`. For example: `ISODate("2023-05-01T13:01:00.000Z"), ISODate("2023-05-01T13:02:00.000Z"), ISODate("2023-05-01T13:04:00.000Z"), ISODate("2023-05-01T13:18:00.000Z")...`

Comment: here is the output of above query just showing one sample here {
  "_id": 12345678901234566 =imei
  "max_time": 1682499619786,
  "min_time": 1682456443752,
  "difference": 719.606 in min
}  since output data is getting bigger, so I am thinking to keep only one record having max diff in output array, for example in case of 1, 2, 3, 4, 18, 19, 20 we can have a record of difference 20 or more, for one imei, this way we will have single record of all those imeis where time difference is bigger than given threshold. idea is to fetch all imeis for those time difference is more than given value

Comment: yes you are correct , since data is coming from gps devices it could be possible that for some devices/ imeis time difference is consistent , may be 1 min or 2 min and for some devices it is inconsistent , so the idea is to fetch all those imeis where time difference is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

One option to find `imei`s where the gap between consecutive documents is greater than `minutes` is to use `$setWindowFields`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      createdon: {
        $gte: start_dt,
        $lte: end_dt
      }
  }},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$imei",
      sortBy: {createdon: 1},
      output: {
        prev: {
          $first: "$createdon",
          window: {documents: [-1, 0]}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$match: {
      $expr: {$gte: [
          {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$createdon", "$prev"]}, 60000]},
          minutes
      ]}
  }},
  {$group: {_id: "$imei"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2NVsvqGga0a)

Comment: query taking too long time to execute, getting timed out, below is the operation details

Comment: "secs_running": 67,
    "microsecs_running": 67352840,
    "op": "command","planSummary": "COLLSCAN",
    "numYields": 78650,
    "locks": {
        "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": "r",
        "Global": "r"
    },
    "waitingForLock": "false",
    "lockStats": {
        "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 78652
            }
        },
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 78652
            }
        },
        
    },

Comment: query is keep on running and getting timed out in db , db is indexed on both imei and createdon, but still too slow

Comment: Is it one index for both of them, or two different indices?

Comment: two different indexes

Comment: You should use one unified index that includes both fields

Comment: created compound index {imei:-1,createdon:-1}, but still not much difference

Comment: `createdon:-1` is used first, thus needs to be first. The order is important